# Why is Jackson wrapping my objects with an extra layer named after the class?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

When I serialize

```
public class FOO {
int field1;
String field2;
}
```

I got the following.

```
{"FOO":{"field1":0,"field2":"value"}}
```

Can you point me how can I make the output look like this

```
{"field1":0,"field2":"value"}
```

Comment: The second form is the default.  You must've configured Jackson to add the wrapper.

Comment: Actually, I used it with spring MVC. So <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" /> and the action method returns new Foo() is the best I can do.

Comment: Then you would need to see how to configure Spring MVC; by the time Jackson is invoked wrapper has already been added

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've figured out how to make it. Actually the problem is that MappingJacksonJsonView has a map So that's why it returns it that way `{"FOO":{"field1":0,"field2":"value"}}`

But If I configured it that way

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
       <beans:property name="extractValueFromSingleKeyModel" value="true" />
</beans:bean>
```

It will serialize the object itself not the whole map. I hope it will help someone else.

Comment: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7543 Automatically expose @PathVariables in the Model causes all methods that have {@PathVariable} parameters to include the {@PathVariable}'s in the model, so the model always contains more than 1 item, so {extractValueFromSingleKeyModel} doesn't work. Do you have any ideas on how to remove the wrapper in this case?

Comment: @candrews I think you would use the [modelKey](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJacksonJsonView.html#setModelKey%28java.lang.String%29) property, like this: `<property name="modelKey" value="FOO"/>`