# Spring 3 ArrayList serialization to JSON with Jackson without wrapping to object (without name)

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have simple resource which should return JSON array, but it returns object in which is array:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/types", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List <JsonObject> types() {
        ArrayList <JsonObject> list=new ArrayList<JsonObject>();
        list.add(new JsonObject("Audi"));
        list.add(new JsonObject("Mercedes"));
        return list;
    }
```

Where JsonObject is simple class with three String atributes (value,id,label).

Returns:

```
{"jsonObjectList":[{"value":"Audi","id":"Audi","label":"Audi"},{"value":"Mercedes","id":"Mercedes","label":"Mercedes"}]}
```

But I what I need (because it's Jquery UI autocomplete expected):

```
[{"value":"Audi","id":"Audi","label":"Audi"},{"value":"Mercedes","id":"Mercedes","label":"Mercedes"}]
```

How to achieve that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Spring 3.1, you should be able to set a property on the `MappingJacksonJsonView` bean called [`extractValueFromSingleKeyModel`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJacksonJsonView.html#setExtractValueFromSingleKeyModel%28boolean%29) to `true` to remove the wrapper.

Oh, seems like this has been asked before [Why is Jackson wrapping my objects with an extra layer named after the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479712/why-is-jackson-wrapping-my-objects-with-an-extra-layer-named-after-the-class)

Comment: Thank youn Andy! This made the trick. I had to migrate to Spring 3.1 and add <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"><property name="extractValueFromSingleKeyModel" value="true" /></bean>

Comment: I didnt... But its the same issue. Unfortunately I wasnt able to google it before I wrote this question. And I really tryed...