# list with error:badcfg Angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

I'm writing applications with Java backend and frontend in AngularJS. My problem is that I can not get data in JavaScript Controller. Although Java server sends the data correctly.

Java - Service:

```
@GET
    @Path("/get/list/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<Room> getList(@PathParam("id") int id) {   
        List<Room> list = service.getList(id);  
        return list;
    }
```

JavaScript - Service:

```
app.factory("BuildingService", function($resource, $q) {
    var BuildingService,
        Rooms = $resource("/api/rest/room/get/list/:id", {
            id: "@id"
        });

    BuildingService = {
        getListRooms: function(id) {
            return Rooms.get({id: id}).$promise;
        }
    };

    return BuildingService;
});
```

JavaScript - Controller:

```
app.controller("BuildingController", function($scope, $routeParams, BuildingService) {
    BuildingService.getListRooms($routeParams.id).then(function(list) {
        $scope.rooms = list;
    }, function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
});
```

error in console:

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/$resource/badcfg?p0=object&p1=array
```

I do not understand this error.

Please help
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning from backend side List i.e. collection of rooms , so you should use `query` method of angular js instead of `get`. In your `BuildingRoomService` change `get` to `query`

Answer (score 0):

The link that the angular error tells you what the problem is

> "To resolve this error, make sure your $resource configuration matches
>   the actual format of the data returned from the server."

the $resource call is expecting a json array response but apparently receives an object.  Check to see what is actually returned by the server, the actual json response.

Your issue may be related to this other issue: [Spring 3 ArrayList serialization to JSON with Jackson without wrapping to object (without name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807781/spring-3-arraylist-serialization-to-json-with-jackson-without-wrapping-to-object)